# boost::asio, timeout async_receive_from, when using single Udp socket to listen to multiple endpoints?

Tags: sockets, udp, boost-asio

I am using a single Udp socket to listen to multiple endpoints.

I want to set timeout for individual `async_receive_from`, to automatically free up resource if appropriate.

But all the timeout examples simply close/reset the socket, while I only want to cancel some overdue receives.

Are there any ways to timeout individual receive?

Or do I have to use individual socket for each endpoints?

Comment: It would help to see how you organized your code, so it becomes less abstract. Right now I could just tell you to "bind extra context into your completion handler" but if that would be clear enough for you, you probably wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: @sehe Thanks for commenting. I checked the completion handler in the examples but the function only accept error_code and nbytes? I think a proper handler for my need would be like `[](int ec, size_t nbyte, udp::endpoint remote){...}`....